# 14.04 support for firewire [IEEE 1394]?

Tags: 14.04, firewire

Does Ubuntu 14.04 support firewire (IEEE 1394)?
Before I purchase a firewire external drive, I would like to have some reasonable expectation of being able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does: I found a firewire external drive adapter lying around, inserted a spare hard drive, plugged it into Linux 14.04 box, and it worked.